# White page after creating project und running `bit start`

Tags: bit.dev

I created a project with bit like in the tutorial (https://bit.dev/docs/getting-started/installing-bit/start-bit-workspace), but when I run `bit start` the page which opens in my browser is completely white.

Comment: Could you provide more insights? Does the terminal show an error? which bit version are you using? platform? Steps to reproduce?

Comment: try using `bit compile` before `bit start`

Comment: @ivarajet Can't this be done automaticly?

Comment: Bit compile is auto ran with bit start.  Try `bit status`.

Comment: `bit` cli has improved since this question was asked, could you please try upgrading the version and its still relevant.

I was running `0.0.888` earlier now `0.1.74`. I'd clean all of the bit previous installations before updating. 

a similar is reported here
https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/7356

additional help is here for uninstall here
https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/7276